# osx DDMathParser - Find Function Token in String

Tags: swift, tokenize, ddmathparser

I try to build an expression string evaluated with `DDMathParser` from user input (string)

for example: 3 + ln(2) + var

I try to use the built-in `Tokenizer` function from `DDMathParser` in order to find all kind of tokens. But using the following code will not find any function tokens:

```
equationInputString = "3+ln(2)+var"
do{
   let token = try Tokenizer(string: equationInputString).tokenize()
   for element in token {
       let tokenString = element.string
       let tokenKind = element.kind
       print(tokenString, ";", tokenKind)
   }
} catch {
       print("Tokenizer error in VC!", error)
}

/* output:
3   ; number
+   ; operator
ln  ; identifier    <-- not recognized as "ln()" function
(   ; operator
2   ; number
)   ; operator
+   ; operator
var ; identifier
*/
```

Is there a way to extract `ln` as function token? Do I need to use another approach within `DDMathParser` to find standard function strings?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DDMathParser author here...

The answer is "it depends". What are you trying to do? Typical usage of DDMathParser would just be to turn the whole thing in to the final `Expression` type, and the recurse through the resulting tree looking for an `Expression` of kind `.function` that has a `name` of `"ln"`.